# How write this SPARQL request?

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

I've the following Ontology built in Protege 4.

[image]

In this Ontology : The main class `Frame` has an datatypeProperty `hasDuration` with domain 'Frame' and range `UnsignedShort`. the Class`ShortFrame` and `LongFrame` are inferred from the class `SizedFrame` with the followiing restriction

Rectriction for ShortFrame class

```
SizedFrame that hasDuration some unsignedLong[<=20]
```

Rectriction for LongFrame class

```
SizedFrame that hasDuration some unsignedLong[>=200]
```

I've manually created an instance of the class `frame` named `frame0`, which has a property `hasDuration` set to `12`.

What is the SPARQL query that I need to get the all `shortFrame`. I hope that `frame0` will be inferred like a `shortFrame` ?

Thanks for any reply !

**Edition: sample query**

```
PREFIX frame: <http://www.semantic.org/sample.owl#>
SELECT ?y WHERE {?y rdf:type frame:Frame}
```

but It is not working ! maybe It is not correct !

Comment: I've add the query in my question. but It is not working. I'm new on SQPARQL. do you have some link to help me getting started ?

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin I realize that this is an old question now, but did you ever get any farther with this?  Jeen B's answer seems like it should retrieve the elements that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, You're going to write some queries for OWL restriction information in SPARQL language. SPARQL is a RDF query language and has no understanding the concepts of OWL. Instead of making a restriction, you can use a data property to define duration value and from that you can get all the shortFrames using SPARQL. Other option I would recommend is use SWRL rules instead of SPARQL. Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi @Swamy, what are differences between SPARQL and SWRL that make the first more interesting than the second in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

The query you give asks for all instance of type `frame:Frame`. Since you want just the short frames, you should adapt it like so:

```
SELECT ?y WHERE {?y a frame:ShortFrame}
```

...but the above will only work if the reasoner understands your restriction and can correctly classify `frame0` as an instance of `ShortFrame`. I am not overly familiar with Protege's syntax for owl restrictions, so I am not 100% sure your restriction expresses what you want it to express.

As an alternative, you can actually express the restriction you require in SPARQL. To query for all frames with a duration of less than 20:

```
SELECT ?y 
WHERE {
   ?y a frame:Frame; 
      frame:hasDuration ?d . 
   FILTER (?d <= 20) 
}
```

Comment: I think that the best query here would include a union of the two that you've shown, since both are ways that a ShortFrame could be recognized.